# QT eventFilter mouseEvent->pos().x() always zero but mouseEvent->pos().y() working fine

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

mouseEvent->pos().x() always return 0. mouseEvent->pos().y() updating on mouse move

```
bool Module3::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event) { 

      QMouseEvent *mouseEvent = static_cast(event);

      if(obj ==scene && event->type() == QEvent::GraphicsSceneMouseMove){

          QToolTip::showText(mouseEvent->pos(),QString::number(mouseEvent->pos().x()) + 
           ", "  + QString::number( mouseEvent->pos().y()));
       }

       return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have undefined behaviour.  If `event->type()` is `QEvent::GraphicsSceneMouseMove` then the real type of event is `QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent*` *not* `QMouseEvent*`.

Try...

```
if (obj == scene && event->type() == QEvent::GraphicsSceneMouseMove) {
    if (auto *mouseEvent = dynamic_cast<QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *>(event)) {
        QToolTip::showText(mouseEvent->scenePos().toPoint(),QString::number(mouseEvent->pos().x()) + 
            ", "  + QString::number( mouseEvent->pos().y()));
    }
}
return false;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply bro. I tried but giving this errors 
error: 'QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent' is an incomplete type

error: cannot dynamic_cast ‘event’ (of type ‘class QEvent*’) to type ‘class QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent*’

Comment: event and tooltip showing but x coordinate is always 0.

Comment: You need to `#include <QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent>` otherwise the compiler can only see a forward declaration.

Comment: bro qinfo working  qInfo()<<"x"<<mouseEvent->scenePos().x()<<"y"<<mouseEvent->scenePos().y();  but    QToolTip shows eroor
                                                                                                                    
     error: no matching function for call to ‘QToolTip::showText(QPointF, const QString)’
                      ", "  + QString::number( mouseEvent->scenePos().y()));
                                                                          ^

Comment: Edited the answer: `mouseEvent->pos()` --> `mouseEvent->pos().toPoint()`.

Comment: bro thanks now working please edit your answer with this change. mouseEvent->pos().toPoint() ---> mouseEvent->scenePos().toPoint(). Thanks for the support. your answer is accepting.